# Nested flex item divs rendered using React not restricting themselves to coequal/correct size?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am attempting to render a custom Table component in React that will render [ "linear"-looking ] **sub-tables**, **if and only if the values of its object `rows` prop are themselves of type 'object'**. To do this I have my parent Table component, that renders a child TableRow component, that then does the conditional rendering of either a SubTable component or a TableInnerSquare component.

So far it works perfectly for the base  condition [ when the properties of the `rows` object are simple ], but when I try to render sub-tables, the TableRows **overflow the width of their container** and I can't figure out how to stop this from happening.

Table component:

```
function Table(props) {
  const { rows, columns, tableWidth, rowHeight } = props;
  // rows here should be an array of rows containing objects w/ properties keyed by column names
  // columns should just be an array of column names
  return (
    <div className='g-table'
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        width: tableWidth,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        margin: '5% auto',
      }}
    >
      <div className='column-id-container'
              style={{
                display: 'flex',
                width: tableWidth,
                height: rowHeight,
              }}
      >
        { columns.map((column,idx) => {
            return (
              <div className='column-id'
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
                  border: '1px solid blue',
                  width: '100%',
                  overflow: 'hidden',
                  padding: '2%',
                }}
                key={idx}
              >
                { column }
              </div>
            );
          }) }
      </div>
      <div className='rows-container'>
        { rows.map((row,idx) => {
            return (
              <TableRow 
                key={idx}
                row={row}
                rowId={idx}
                tableWidth={tableWidth}
                rowHeight={rowHeight}
                columns={columns}
              />
            );
          }) }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

TableRow component:

```
function TableRow(props) {
  const { columns, row, rowId, tableWidth, rowHeight } = props;
  // row should be an object with keys for each column here;
  // columns should be an array
  console.log('columns:');
  console.log(columns);
  console.log('row:');
  console.log(row);
  return (
    <div className='table-row'
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        width: tableWidth,
      }}
    >
     { columns.map((property,idx) => {
          if (typeof (row[property]) === 'object') {
            return (
              <SubTable
                dataObject={row[property]}
                rowHeight={rowHeight} // so for the SubTablesTable the row should be an object of objects
                key={idx}
              />
            );
          } else {
            return (
              <TableInnerSquare
                innerData={row[property]}
                rowHeight={rowHeight}
                key={idx}
              />
            );
          }
        }) }
    </div>
  );
}
```

SubTable:

```
function SubTable(props) {
  const { dataObject, rowHeight } = props;
  console.log('dataObject:');
  console.log(dataObject);
  return (
    <div className='sub-table'
      style={{
        width: 'auto',
        display: 'flex',
        flex: '1',
      }}
    >
         { Object.entries(dataObject).map((entry,idx) => {
            return (
              <div className='sub-table-inner'
                style={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  overflow: 'hidden',
                }}
              >
                <TableInnerSquare
                  rowHeight={rowHeight}
                  innerData={entry[0]}
                />
                <TableInnerSquare
                  rowHeight={rowHeight}
                  innerData={entry[1]}
                />
              </div>
            );
          }) }
    </div>
  );
}
```

TableInnerSquare:

```
function TableInnerSquare(props) {
  const { innerData, rowHeight } = props;
  return (
    <div 
      className='table-inner-square'
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'gold',
        border: '1px solid red',
        height: rowHeight,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        padding: '2%',
        width: '100%',
      }}
    >
      { innerData }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help figuring out how to restrict `TableRow`s containing `SubTable`s to having width `tableWidth` [ which like I said the `TableRow`s containing `TableInnerSquare`s already seem to do? ] would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can set `overflow: hidden` on a div, *but its parent divs will still recognize the content as present and grow to contain it*. You need to set `overflow: hidden` on the div with class `sub-table` [ in component `SubTable` ] here, in order for the sub-tables to hide the overflows of their inner divs.